# Any api is there for getting Sales by Ticket Type?

Tags: eventbrite

I need to fetch details of attendees based on ticket type  and also sales related information

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [event_list_attendees](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_list_attendees/) API method: 
http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_list_attendees/

That page contains a 'Try it Now!' button that allows you to test the API call, and review the response data.
You will need to login to access any private data.  Authenticated users should see a ticket_id attached to each [attendee](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/attendees/) record.